# How to only get records under a certain column

Tags: sql

This is a simple question about sql query and I tried to find a way to do it but strangely couldn't find an answer.

I have a table (products) with multiple columns. I want to get all records but only the values under a certain column (id).

Sorry about the newbie question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the columns you want in the `SELECT`, for example:

```
SELECT id
FROM dbo.Products
```

Even if you want all columns it's better to specify all by name instead of using `SELECT * ...`

Why? Read this: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)